# Detect the latest continuous non null rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table like this with a primary key on id, date combination -

```
id  date    value
1   2002-02-28  NULL
1   2002-03-31  NULL
1   2002-04-30  10
1   2002-05-31  5
1   2002-10-31  4
1   2002-11-30  NULL
1   2002-12-31  0.7
1   2003-01-31  9
1   2003-02-28  NULL
2   2002-12-31  0.7
2   2003-11-30  0.10
```

I need to select the latest sequence of values without NULL (if any). The expected output -

```
id  date    value
1   2002-12-31  0.7
1   2003-01-31  9
2   2002-12-31  0.7
2   2003-11-30  0.10
```

Explanation:

1. For id = 1, the latest NULL value occurs on 2003-02-28 and the latest sequence is consist of 2 rows with value .7 and 9 since on 2002-11-30 there is another NULL found, therefore, all previous rows are ignored.
2. For id = 2, there are no NULL values, so we take the 2 rows.

I have a working solution with 3-4 queries with some other calculation. But I think it could be done within 2 queries (or a subquery). Remember that the dataset is huge and contains 30-40 million rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE
    AS
    (
       SELECT id
             ,[date]
             ,Value
             ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID DESC,[DATE] DESC) AS Rnk
       FROM TableA
       WHERE Value IS NULL
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM TableA Res1
    WHERE ([Date] >= (SELECT [date] FROM CTE WHERE ID = Res1.ID AND Rnk = 2)
    AND [Date] <= (SELECT [date] FROM CTE WHERE ID = Res1.ID AND Rnk = 1))
    AND Value IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Sorry but there could and always be more than 3 rows for each id in the output.

Comment: if the id's are same and the dates are different still those records should be pulled. are you trying to pull all the records for the top 2 dates descending on all id's?

Comment: Edited the code to get the latest records between two latest NULLs. Hope this helps

Comment: I will check and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there must be a cleaner way to do this but I'm failing to come up with it at the moment:

```
declare @t table (id int not null, date date not null, value decimal(5,2) null)
insert into @t(id,date,value) values
(1,'20020228',NULL),    (1,'20020331',NULL),    (1,'20020430',10  ),
(1,'20020531',5   ),    (1,'20021031',4   ),    (1,'20021130',NULL),
(1,'20021231',0.7 ),    (1,'20030131',9   ),    (1,'20030228',NULL),
(2,'20021231',0.7 ),    (2,'20031130',0.10)

; With Latest as (
    select id,MAX(date) as date from @t where value is not null
    group by id
), LatestNull as (
    select t.id,MAX(t.date) as date
    from @t t
        inner join
        Latest l
            on
                t.id = l.id and
                t.date < l.date
    where
        t.value is null
    group by t.id
)
select
    *
from
    @t t
        left join
    LatestNull ln
        on
            t.id = ln.id and
            t.date > ln.date and
            t.value is not null
where ln.id is not null or
not exists(select * from LatestNull ln2 where ln2.id = t.id)
```

On the plus side, I think it does reasonable clearly follow your spec for the problem so it should be correct. Results:

```
id          date       value                                   id          date
----------- ---------- --------------------------------------- ----------- ----------
1           2002-12-31 0.70                                    1           2002-11-30
1           2003-01-31 9.00                                    1           2002-11-30
2           2002-12-31 0.70                                    NULL        NULL
2           2003-11-30 0.10                                    NULL        NULL
```

Comment: It uses more query than my current implementation. Nice try though. I am looking for a 2 or max 3 query solution

Comment: @Shiblu - you shouldn't be attempting to optimize SQL by counting "queries" - you should analyse plans and indexes. Try to write code that *clearly asks for what you want* and then trust the optimizer to do the right job.

Comment: Thanks. I will check the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the recursive CTE

```
with rownum_cte as
(
  select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) rn
  from @t
),
recursive_cte as
(
  select t1.*
  from rownum_cte t1
  where value is not null and date >= all
  (
    select date
    from rownum_cte t2
    where value is not null and t1.id= t2.id
  )
  union all 
  select rownum_cte.*
  from recursive_cte
  join rownum_cte on recursive_cte.id = rownum_cte.id and rownum_cte.value is not null and recursive_cte.rn + 1 = rownum_cte.rn
)
select recursive_cte.id, recursive_cte.date, recursive_cte.value
from recursive_cte
order by recursive_cte.id, recursive_cte.date
```

[demo I](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=56514801b1fef4ffca20e599498f503e) - I have used the @Damien_The_Unbeliever script for the data (thanks)

I have created another recursive version that uses maximum date per `id`. Therefore, that `ALL` construct is replaced by a subquery computing these maximums:

```
With rownum_cte as
(
  select t.*, row_number() over (partition by t.id order by t.date desc) rn
  from @t t
  join (
    select id, max(date) as maxdate 
    from @t 
    where value is not null
    group by id  
  ) lt on t.id= lt.id and t.date <= lt.maxdate 
),
recursive_cte as
(
  select t1.*
  from rownum_cte t1
  where value is not null and t1.rn = 1
  union all 
  select rownum_cte.*
  from recursive_cte
  join rownum_cte on recursive_cte.id = rownum_cte.id and rownum_cte.value is not null and recursive_cte.rn + 1 = rownum_cte.rn
)
select recursive_cte.id, recursive_cte.date, recursive_cte.value
from recursive_cte
order by recursive_cte.id, recursive_cte.date
```

[demo II](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a579dd40bc7f806405f444d9521bb01a)

Answer (score 0):

After several algorithm attempts, I think this may simplify to what is below... 
 Here, the CTE identifies the MAX null date, previous NULL date.  From the id and dates returned by the CTE, I INNER JOIN to acquire the relevant dates in the temp table that are within the range.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (id int, date date, value decimal(12,2))

INSERT INTO @temp
VALUES
(1, '2002-02-28', NULL), (1, '2002-03-31', NULL), (1, '2002-04-30', 10), (1, '2002-05-31', 5),
(1, '2002-10-31', 4), (1, '2002-11-30', NULL), (1, '2002-12-31', 0.7), (1, '2003-01-31', 9),
(1, '2003-02-28', NULL), (2, '2002-12-31', 0.7), (2, '2003-11-30', 0.10);

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT dT.*
          ,(SELECT MAX(date) FROM @temp T3 WHERE T3.id = dT.id AND T3.value IS NULL AND T3.date < dT.MaxNULLDate) [PreviousNullDate]              
      FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT id
                  ,(SELECT MAX(date) FROM @temp T2 WHERE T2.id = T1.id AND T2.value IS NULL) [MaxNULLDate]    
              FROM @temp T1 
           ) AS dT
) 

SELECT T.*
  FROM cte INNER JOIN @temp T ON cte.id = T.id
                             AND T.value IS NOT NULL
                             AND T.date > COALESCE(cte.PreviousNullDate, '')
                             AND T.date < COALESCE(cte.MaxNULLDate, '9999-12-31')
ORDER BY cte.id, T.date
```

This gives output:

```
id  Start       value
1   2002-12-31  0.70
1   2003-01-31  9.00
2   2002-12-31  0.70
2   2003-11-30  0.10
```